# delete function question

Tags: contract-development

I have the function:

```js
contract TaskContract {

  function deleteTask(uint256 taskId, bool isDeleted) external {
      if (taskToOwner[taskId] == msg.sender) {
                tasks[taskId].isDeleted = isDeleted;
                emit DeleteTask(taskId, isDeleted);
      }
  }
```

My question and what I want to achive is to call that function from other smart contract and be able to delete the task item as taskToOwner[msg.sender].

All answers appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To call the deleteTask() function from another contract, you can use the address type to specify the address of the contract that contains the deleteTask() function. Then, you can use the .call() or .send() method to execute the function on that contract. For example

```
contract OtherContract {
  address taskContractAddress = 0x123456...; // address of the contract containing the deleteTask() function

  function deleteTask(uint256 taskId) public {
    // Call the deleteTask() function on the contract at taskContractAddress
    taskContractAddress.call(bytes4(keccak256("deleteTask(uint256,bool)")), taskId, true);
  }
}
```

In the example above, the deleteTask() function in OtherContract accepts a taskId as input and calls the deleteTask() function in TaskContract, passing taskId and true as arguments.

The .call() method is used to execute the function in a read-only manner, which means it cannot modify the state of the contract. If you want to modify the state of the contract (e.g. update the isDeleted property of the task), you can use the .send() method instead. However, be aware that using .send() can result in the loss of funds if the transaction fails.

It's also important to note that the deleteTask() function in TaskContract has an if statement that checks that taskToOwner[taskId] == msg.sender. This means that only the owner of the task can delete it. When calling the deleteTask() function from another contract, the msg.sender will be the address of the contract that is calling the function, not the original caller. Therefore, you will need to make sure that the contract calling the deleteTask() function has the necessary permissions to delete the task.

Comment: I know how to call other smart contract. My question is how to make sure that the contract calling the deleteTask() function has the necessary permissions to delete the task. How to rewrite function with if statement to check it. Any ideas ?

Comment: One way to do this is to add a mapping in the TaskContract contract that maps addresses to a boolean value that indicates whether the address has the necessary permissions to delete tasks. You can then add an additional check in the deleteTask function to verify that the caller's address is mapped to true in the mapping.

Comment: Could you please provide/edit the code ? Thank You!

Comment: Sorry but this place is to get answers, not have someone do work for you. I gave you some context so it's best you try to apply it yourself.

Comment: I don’t agree with You. It’s not doing work for someone as I provided You my code, and an answer would be your few lines of code. Your context is right, but I believe you are not sure how to apply it. Anyways thank You for your time!

Comment: I know exactly how to apply it, in fact I have the code example ready to go. I just don't want to write any code for you because you will just copy & paste it without learning. It's a fairly simple task to add mapping. If you want development done, pay for it or do it yourself.

Hint: the answer to both your question here & below are fixed by the same code but since you said I don't know how to apply it, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to understand how to modify the function so that another contract has access to delete any entry.

One options is to add a new access check to the function and only a contract at address X (here denoted as `0xabc`) can call that - or the original task owner.

Here's an example:

```
address deleter = 0xabc;

function deleteTask(uint256 taskId, bool isDeleted) external {
    if (taskToOwner[taskId] == msg.sender || msg.sender == deleter) {
        tasks[taskId].isDeleted = isDeleted;
        emit DeleteTask(taskId, isDeleted);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I can’t hardcode the address because taskToOwner[taskId] is mapped to msg.sender which is creating new smart contract when adding the task in the other function. I need to rewrite the deleteTask() function to know who is who. And not any entry. msg.sender to taskId number.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what you need. Please modify the original question to add details which would help users to understand the problem